# How to set Cache control for external cloud files

Tags: php, caching, controls, performance

Hey Guys,
I was bent on improving my page speed factors and yesterday I got some cloud space on rackspacecloud. Now before this i was serving static content from a cookieless domain with proper cache control through htaccess.

Now after I moved on to cloud my htaccess does not control the cloud files. There is a TTL parameter on rackspace that sets values for how long the files should stay on CDN. That value reflects on my Page Speed settings (google + firebug). Now the default setting can me maximum 72 hours but I need something above 7 days. I need some api for that and its kinda complex..

Is there any way I can enforce cache control on my cloud files? 
what do these query strings do domain.com/file.css?cache=0.54454334 ???

Do they achieve what I am looking for? 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may have figured it out already, but heres a link to checkout: [Set far-future expires headers with Rackspace Cloud Files (sort of)](http://cutfromthenorth.com/set-far-future-expires-headers-with-rackspace-cloud-files/).

He is using the [cloudfiles PHP API](https://github.com/rackspace/php-cloudfiles), and so am I. You can manually set the TTL (aka expires) headers to whatever you want to. Right now I have them set to 365 days (maybe a little excessive).

The documentation is fairly straightforward. If you need any help, this code should help you get started:

```
<?php

// include the API
require('cloudfiles.php');

// cloud info
$username = "myusername"; // username
$key = "c2dfa30bf91f345cf01cb26d8d5ea821"; // api key

// Connect to Rackspace
$auth = new CF_Authentication($username, $key);
$auth->authenticate();
$conn = new CF_Connection($auth);

// Get the container we want to use
$container = $conn->create_container('images');

// store file information
$filename  = "images/logo.jpg";

// upload file to Rackspace
$object = $container->create_object($filename);
$object->load_from_filename($localfile);

// make public, and set headers
$container->make_public(86400 * 365); // expires headers set to 365 days

?>
```